# Main function not running? CONFUSED

Tags: python, program-entry-point, fibonacci

I am trying to program a module for a class but my main() function does not work I presume the code is right but when I input a number it just goes to the next line, does not stop execution and just allows me to input further numbers, going to the next line afterward - ad infinitum.

I tread into the main function of python but I am still confused.

```
# Uses python3
import sys

def get_fibonacci_last_digit_naive(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n

    previous = 0
    current  = 1

    for _ in range(n - 1):
        previous, current = current, previous + current

    return current % 10
def fast_fibL(b):
    a = []
    a.append(0)
    a.append(1)
    n = 0
    if (b == 0):
        return 0

    if (b == 1):
        return 1

    for i in range(b):
        c = a[i] + a[i + 1]
        a.append(c)
        n += 1

    return(a[n])

def get_fib_last_digit_fast(e):
    b = fast_fibL(e)
    return b % 10

def main():
    input = sys.stdin.read()
    n = int(input)
    print(get_fib_last_digit_fast(n))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expect the code to return the the last digit of the n-th Fibonacci number entered.

Comment: You don't want to use `sys.stdin.read()` here... it will read until it hits the end of file (EOF).  The enter key does not signify the end of the file, only the start of a new line.  You can either try `sys.stdin.readline()` or use the built-in function `input()` instead (assuming you're using Python 3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `input = sys.stdin.read()`, use the [built-in `input()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

```
def main():
    n = int(input('Enter an integer: '))
    print(get_fib_last_digit_fast(n))
```

Answer (score 2):

The program is waiting for your input, since you're using `stdin.read()`. This waits until the input is terminated by (for instance) pressing ctrl-D.
Normally you'd use [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) for this, which reads one line from stdin.

```
def main():
    line = input('> ')
    n = int(line)
    print(get_fib_last_digit_fast(n))
```